# Literacy rates of Asian countries

Tags: education, census, demographics, asia

What are the literacy rates of Asian countries (Myanmar, Bhutan, Pakistan, China, Nepal) for last five censuses?

Comment: Take a look at the Barro and Lee dataset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think **data.worldbank.org** is going to be your best bet for getting this information.

Here is a direct link to the indicator for "Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, both sexes (%)" (`SE.ADT.LITR.ZS`)

http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SE.ADT.LITR.ZS

You can click "Databank" from that link to go to a table generator where you can limit your query to specific countries and years.